# How do I access the start of a fortran array from the end of a do loop over the array?

Tags: arrays, performance, fortran

In my do loop I need to access the i+1 th element of the array. For the last element, this needs to be the first value in the array.

So looping over the array /1,2,3/ I'd want the output 2,3,1,2,3,...

I've written a slightly clunky way to do this using a variable for the index and MOD, I was wondering if there was a better solution? I also don't want to slow down the rest of the code (for example if I'm doing this operation hundreds of thousands of times).

```
program array_test
    implicit none
    
    real, dimension(3) :: arr
    integer :: i, idx
    data arr /1.0,2.0,3.0/
    
    do i=1,size(arr)+2
        idx = mod(i,size(arr))
        write(*,*) "Index i+1", idx+1, arr(idx+1)
    enddo
end program
```

which outputs

```
 Index i+1           2   2.00000000
 Index i+1           3   3.00000000
 Index i+1           1   1.00000000
 Index i+1           2   2.00000000
 Index i+1           3   3.00000000
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, is there any problem you have? `mod` is quite fast. Alternatively, you can split the loops into two.

Comment: I now realise that the problem I had was that this doesn't work on arbitrary indexing, e.g. `write(*,*) "Index i+2", idx+2, arr(idx+2)` accesses the array out of bounds

Comment: @tgpz An alternative, would be to extend the array by `j` elements, where `j` is the number of elements ahead you want to look. This means `1` in the first example and `2` in the second example. You would copy the first `j` elements of the original array in the newly added elements in the extended array and loop over the new array from `1` to `n`, where `n` is the length of the original array.

Comment: @PetrH I'll probably do something like that, thanks.